# local storage don't save data after page reload react

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I need to keep some data in local storage. I am making new object and put it into local storage. Then I see what is in local storage and I see changed data. After page reload local storage keeping default data. What the reason of this?

this is my function code:

```
const changeTitle = () => {
    const newObjData = cardData.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === cardId) {
        item.title = inputValue
      }
      return item
    })
    setCardsData(newObjData)
    localStorage.setItem('cardsData', JSON.stringify(newObjData))

    const newObjCards = cards.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === cardId) {
        item.title = inputValue
      }
      return item
    })
    localStorage.setItem('cards', JSON.stringify(newObjCards))

    setIsEdit(false)
  }
```

How I get all data from storage for component

```
const [comments, setComments] = useState<ICommentsData[]>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('comments') as string));
  const columns: IColumnData[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('columns') as string);
  const cardData: ICardData[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cardsData') as string);
  const cards: ICard[] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cards') as string);
  const [colTitle, setColTitle] = useState<string>("");
  const [cardsData, setCardsData] = useState<ICardData[]>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cardsData') as string));
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const [isEdit, setIsEdit] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCardsData(cardsData.filter((item) => item.id === cardId))
    setComments(comments.filter((item) => item.cardId === cardId))
    getColTitle()
  }, [isEdit])
```

Comment: Put all your component code to see how you're getting the value from local storage, the code above only shows that you're setting the object into local storage

Comment: Perhaps this method runs when the component is first rendered (after page reloads)

Comment: @GuyML It runs only on form submit

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create a custom hook useLocalSotrage [here as an example](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage). And try to use it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).